# How to create & sync WordPress website between multiple computers?

Tags: windows, dropbox, xampp, wordpress, ampps

I'm trying to start creating a WordPress website, and I need to sync my work between two **Windows 7** PCs.

I've tried xampp & ampps, for editing and viewing php files. But haven't yet tried installing WordPress on either of them. On ampps it's easy to install it, but I had to uninstalling without testing it cause I'm looking for an app that could sync the content too!

Here's what I've tried:

- Install portable xampp to C:\downloads\xampp\
- Move the htdocs and mysql folders to dropbox, as [Suggested In This Tutorial](http://www.mysitetestyes.altervista.org/work-with-xampp-on-dropbox/).
- Synced my work convenientally uptil 2-3 days.

After 2-3 days, my Dropbox got currupted, and I had to reinstall it. Don't know why it happened but the dropbox was stuck on uploading about 800 files which it wasn't even uploading. Folders showed all files synced, but still dropbox was uploading some 800 files...

Anyways, I removed the htdocs + sql folders from dropbox, and currently have no way to backup or sync my work with dropbox.

My question:

- Is there any way to sync a WordPress site while working on it via Dropbox?
- How can I do this with AMPPS?
- Does wordpress require SQL?
- If I move the htdocs(xampp) or www(AMPPS) folder to Dropbox, would that suffice for the sync? Or is sql required too?

Comment: Do you need constant sync? If not, why not put the thing in version control?

Comment: I don't require constant sync... only need to access it between home and work computers... Was planning to use pen drive for this purpose until I read your comment...: What is version control?

Comment: Related [How do I have Wordpress keep its database in the same directory as other files (for sharing via Dropbox)?](https://superuser.com/q/565523/152004)